# Can you authenticate with Passport without redirecting?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I have the following working code to authenticate through the passport-local strategy:

```
  app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/api/login/success',
    failureRedirect : '/api/login/error',
    failureFlash : true
  }));
  app.get('/api/login/error', function(req, res) {
    res.send(401, {error: req.flash('loginMessage')});
  });
  app.get('/api/login/success', function(req, res) {
    res.send(200, {user: req.user});
  });
```

However, ideally I want to handle the errors and success messages from one express route, and not redirect to two extra routes.

Is this possible? I tried using a 'custom callback' but that seemed to error out on serializing users for some reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use custom callback, such as:

```
passport.authenticate('local', function (err, account) {
    req.logIn(account, function() {
        res.status(err ? 500 : 200).send(err ? err : account);
    });
})(this.req, this.res, this.next);
```

In err object you can find all needed errors, which was appeared at authentication.

Comment: Perfect! Do you happen to know if there's an equivalent of `req.logIn` for local signups? Other than that, many thanks!

Comment: You just need to write other strategy, which would call function for registration new user

Answer (score 6):

Are you using Mongoose?
Try adding this to your server.js/index.js

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

This to your routes index.js

```
var auth = require('./auth');
app.post('/api/auth/login', passport.authenticate('local'),auth.login);
```

auth.js:

```
var UserModel = require('../models/user');
var User = new UserModel();

exports.login = function(req, res) {
    var user = req.user;
    req.login(user, function(err) {
        //if error: do something
        return res.status(200).json(user)
    });
};
```

Add this to model index.js

```
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
    usernameField: 'email',
    usernameLowerCase: 'true'
});
```

I'm making a lot of assumptions on structure and packages here. but this should work

**EDIT**

For custom callbacks:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Here you instead of `res.redirect` you can use something like `return res.status(404).json("Not Found)`

See docs for more information : http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/

Comment: Everything is working as far as authenticating goes, it's just that the callback (auth.login in your case) only gets fired when the login is succesful. I also want to give messages when it fails, which you can't do inside the strategy.

Comment: Thanks @Clto, you've inadvertently answered like 4 random questions I had

Comment: do you also have the user model?