# iOS CORS ajax request readyState 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, cors

I am trying to make a CORS login `AJAX` call from my iPhone, using `$.ajax` but it fails (reaches the `fail` callback) with this `jqXHR` object state:

```
{ 
 readyState: 0,
 status: 0,
 statusText: "error"
}
```

On `PC` it works ok, the requests succeeds.

On `iOS`, even though the request fails I am actually logged if I refresh the page and on the server  (**Node.js**) I can see it as a successful login request.

The difference is that in Chrome, desktop the `POST` login request is redirected directly to the `loginOk` page, while the `POST` request from `iOS` first triggers a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request that reaches the `loginOk` page.

Chrome request (from Node.js console):

```
POST /login 302
GET /loginOk 200
```

iOS request (from Node.js console):

```
POST /login 302
OPTIONS /ok 200
```

The CORS request is from **localhost** to the node server, **localhost:3000**.

This is my `AJAX` call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://192.168.1.2:3000/login",
    data: formData,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
})
```

And, this is my CORS middleware:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'myCookie');

    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

Comment: How I "solved" the problem atm is simply add a condition in my ajax `fail` callback to simply reload the page on fail. The problem with this is that it only works locally, when I deploy to an online host, with real different domains it won't log me in anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is redirecting with HTTP 302 response to the POST request. This is only allowed while the request is simple. But as OPTIONS request is being generated from iOS, you will not be able to do redirects like that.

The reason is that according to CORS specification, all kinds of HTTP redirects (301, 302, 303, 307, or 308) are disallowed for preflight requests and will result in network error.

I would suggest removing redirection altogether and making another call to the server after authentication process is over.

Comment: Think is that I use passport authentication and by default it has a `successRedirect` and `failureRedirect`. In the `sucessRedirect` I return a custom cookie to be set. I might try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859349/can-you-authenticate-with-passport-without-redirecting

Comment: Removing the redirect fixed this issue. I did not know that redirects aren't allowed in CORS.

Comment: I have to mention that for the login to work I had to edit Safari settings on iOS and set something like Always allow cookies. By default Safari doesn't allow CORS cookies (you can't set a cookie for another domain). I think I will fix this but actually not using cookies and set the session ID through a GET param not a cookie.