# Passport/Express login failure without redirect

Tags: express, passport.js

**Objective**

On user successful authentication, I want to redirect to another page (works)
On unsuccessful authentication, I want a message to flash (incorrect password) 
without reloading the page

**Problem**

on unsuccessful attempts it redirects to same url but with a blank page showing only "unauthorized"

**Endpoint Code**

```
app.post('/', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/hospital',
        failureRedirect : '',
        failureFlash : true
    }));
```

**Local Code**

```
 passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        models.User.findById(id).then(function (user) {
            done(null, user.dataValues);
        }).error(function (err) {
            done(err, null);
        });
    });

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'username',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function (req, username, password, done) {

            hashedPass = crypto.createHash('md5').update(password).digest("hex");
            models.User.findOne({where: {username: username}}).then(function (result) {

                if (!result)  done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user'});

                if (result.password !== hashedPass)  done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect password'});
                else done(null, result);

            });
        }));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you authenticate with Passport without redirecting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859349/can-you-authenticate-with-passport-without-redirecting)

Comment: @Ahmedfaragmostafa I should have mentioned it in the question, I tried the answer in that link and no luck