# Passport authenticate return json instead of redirect for angular

Tags: angular, express, passport.js

I am trying to return json data from my successful sign-in or login. (This is so angular can grab it and do a redirect on the front end, not express redirecting on the back end).

I have tried other answers I've seen on here and it makes sense and should work as far as I know. This answer in particular: [Can you authenticate with Passport without redirecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859349/can-you-authenticate-with-passport-without-redirecting) says it has working code but if I try the res.send I get the error below.

Here is my api:

```
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/loginSucceeded',
    failureRedirect: '/loginFailed'
  }
));

app.get('/loginSucceeded', (req, res) => {
  res.json({message:'/posts'});
});

app.get('/loginFailed', (req, res) => {
  res.json({message:'/login'});
});
```

at Promise._fulfill (C:\micromotion\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
    at PromiseArray._resolve (C:\micromotion\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:126:19)
    at PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (C:\micromotion\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:144:14)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\micromotion\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:26)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\micromotion\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\micromotion\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\micromotion\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\micromotion\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\micromotion\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)

I have tried several other things like switching the success and failure redirect with a function and get the same error. Does that mean the error is within my passport strategy? I'm having a tough time understanding it, but it was pulled from a tutorial:

```
 passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(

    {
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
      passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },


    function(req, email, password, done) {
      var generateHash = function(password) {
        return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
      };

      User.findOne({
        where: {
          email: email
        }
      }).then(function(user) {
        if (user)
        {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: 'That email is already taken'
          });

        } else

        {
          var userPassword = generateHash(password);
          var data =
          {
            email: email,
            password: userPassword,
            firstname: req.body.firstname,
            lastname: req.body.lastname
          };

          User.create(data).then(function(newUser, created) {

            if (!newUser) {
              return done(null, false);
            }

            if (newUser) {
              return done(null, newUser);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  ));
```

Any my angular code that calls it, but shouldn't matter really:

```
  signup(data){
    return this.http.post('/api/signup', data)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
       // this.router.navigate([response.url])
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it using custom callbacks from their docs. Guess I just need to understand the req/res/next better.

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
  passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info){
    if(err){return next(err);}
    if(!user){return res.send({redirect: '/signup'});}
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.send({redirect: '/posts'});
    });
  }) (req, res, next);
});
```

and angular:

```
  signup(data){
    return this.http.post('/api/signup', data)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        var r = response.json();
       this.router.navigate([r.redirect])
      });
  }
```